# JDBC ResultSet SQL error

Tags: sql, jsp, jdbc

I wrote the following part which is a Java method with two STRING arguments login and pass, representing a user's login name and password, to check whether the user is found in a database table.

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();

ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" 
        + login + "' AND passwd = '" + pass + "'");
```

The code when tested worked correctly. I read in a book that there are situations where it could potentially generate an SQL error but it does not mention exactly the circumstances under which the above code could result in an SQL error. Could you please briefly expain me these situations? And also how can I write a version of the code that would prevent the possibilityof such an error occuring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that this piece of code is vulenrable to `SQL Injection`. To avid that you can use `Prepared Statements`. This might be one potential threat the book might be talking about.

http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

example for using prepared statement

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND passwd = ?";

PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);

ps.setString(1, login);
ps.setString(2, passwd);

Resultset rs = rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: For example:

`String login = "username';drop database;commit";`

Comment: @BorisPavlović nice scary example

Comment: @Zohaib: but it depends a lot on the database. Boris' attack would not work with Oracle or PostgreSQL because they don't allow multiple statements within a single `executeQuery()` call. I think (only?) SQL Server and MySQL are vunerable to that specific attack.

Answer (score 0):

You should have to write a code that [prevent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) sql injection. Use `PreparedStatement` (Parameterized statements) and `Stored proc` instead of hard-coded sql strings.